# Giving invalid query in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query and I dont know what is wrong with the code.

```
    if($_GET['btn1']=="Submit"){    
        $No=$_GET['text_input'];
        $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  order WHERE `ModelNo`='$No'");
        if (!$result1) { 
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

This is the error message it gives,
Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order WHERE No='1071764'' at line 1
Please somebody help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as you can see `ORDER` is a Reserved keyword in mysql, You can escape it using backticks.

```
SELECT * FROM  `order` WHERE `ModelNo`='$No'
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

To avoid problems like this, do not use keywords that are present on the [list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) if possible. `:D`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues here
 1. type `order` instead of order, coz order - it is reserved mysql word 
 2. do some validation to GET params